# GetElementsByName with array like name

Tags: javascript, foreach, getelementsbyname

i often use this notation when i name my controls in order to get an array in POST or GET.

```
<input name="color[1]" type="text" />
<input name="color[2]" type="text" />
<input name="color[3]" type="text" />
```

so in my scripts i can do

```
<?php $data=$_GET["color"]; 
for each ($color as $key=>$value) {
   doSomething();
} ?>
```

Often happens that i need to get those id back in javascript , but i cannot get them , so i often add an ID to each element in html like that

```
<input name="color[3]" id="color_3" type="text" />
```

so that i can use document.getElementsById('color_3')

Instead i would like to find way to use document.getElementsByName(color[3])... 
but i cannot really get it to work.

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<input name="color[3]" id="color_3" type="text" />

var element = document.getElementsByName("color[3]");

alert(element[0].id);
```

It works fine .. The thing you should have in your mind is **Return type is an array of elements not a single element**

Comment: I'm gonna try again. i tried and tried and tried with firefox console....
OK it works... i can swear this morning, in my room, was not working..

Any chance i can write <color[3]>xxx</color[3]>  in some xml? i don't think i can write xml tag name with "[" inside.

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi You can write xml in that way .. See here : http://jsfiddle.net/xE6bh/

Comment: i get "non well formed" if i write like that...

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><cose><myform quale="ali">
 <ali_id><va>2</va></ali_id>
 <ali_descrizione><va>Prosciutto</va></ali_descrizione>
 <ali_ordine><va>0.00</va></ali_ordine>
 <ali_prezzo><va>6.00</va></ali_prezzo>
 <ali_listino><ck>N</ck></ali_listino><ing_id[1]><ck>S</ck></ing_id[1]><ing_id[2]><ck>S</ck></ing_id[2]><ing_id[8]><ck>S</ck></ing_id[8]></myform></cose>

Comment: Yupp i tried .. Issue is because of ']' but don't know the reason

Comment: Is not allow in xml specs i see.
i solved doing <ing_id index="2">xxx</ing_id> and writing a bit of javascript that check if there is attribute index, and then modify the  tagname  name +'['+key +']' and it works.

Answer (score 11):

If you want *all* of the color inputs, you can use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) instead to query for the name attribute:

```
document.querySelectorAll("input[name^='color[']")
```

This looks through the document for all `input` tags whose name attribute starts with `color[`. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Blade0rz/Lht9L/1/) is a fiddle for this.

If you only want `color[3]`, you can use:

```
var color3 = document.getElementsByName("color[3]");
console.log(color3[0]);
```